# JSPdf autotable header border

Tags: pdf, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

How to create border in Header? I am using jspdf autotable to create table but cannot find any idea to apply border to header. Is there any hook that can be used to create header border?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the header styles:

```
doc.autotable(columns, data, {
    headerStyles: {
        lineWidth: 1,
        lineColor: [255, 0, 0]
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice Simon!... but I've a question: What about if I want to only add the top and bottom borders?

Comment: Not supported by the library right now as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

As of today (version 3.5.25) the property name is `headStyles` and still different border widths is not supported.

Example:

```
    autoTable(doc, {
        headStyles: {
            lineWidth: 0.5, // 1 is too thick for me
            lineColor: [255, 0, 0] // Or gray level single value from 0-255
        }
    })
```

I use the imported method version (autoTable) in TypeScript.